# How to write/read and add two numbers from RAM?

Tags: vhdl, ram, xilinx

I am a student and I have been working with Xilinx tools for 2 weeks. I would like to create a circuit that reads 2 8-bit numbers and store them in 2 different ram blocks. Then I would like to read the numbers and add them. I created the following: Circuit and accompanied that schematic with the following test bench:

[image: circuit]

```
tb : PROCESS
BEGIN
    WE<='1';
    clear<='0';
    data<="00000001";
    ci<='0';
    add<='1';
    CE<='1';
    WAIT for 25 ns; -- will wait forever

    WE<='0';
    clear<='1';
    data<="00000000";
    ci<='0';
    add<='1';
    CE<='1';
    WAIT for 25 ns; -- will wait forever
END PROCESS;
```

(There is also another process for the clock but I didn't show it here.)

The results of my simulation are correct, but at the begining of the simulation I have those `XXXXXXXX` instead of `00000000`. What is the error?

[image: image of simulation]

Comment: First of all, what platform you're using? Zynq? Some Spartan FPGA? Also what tools are you using (Vivado or ISE)? Are you going to make a fully functional system or just a simulation?

Comment: I am using ISE design web pack . I just want to do this as an exercise  theoretically i don't use any platform

Comment: I am not a VHDL or Digital Design expert, but I believe that you should be asserting at some point a RESET signal. You see, the XXs you're getting are during the first cycle of the simulation, while you haven't any real results yet.

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Why is `data` not changing in your simulation? `WE` and `clear` both update after 25ns, but `data` remains constant at `00000001`. Regarding the X's seen for `result`, I would imagine it is due to the way the RAM is implemented (possibly sync write/async read); It will take some number of cycles (appears to be one in your sim) for values that are written/read to propagate through to the result

Comment: Hello gsm. Actually you are right. The data have to change! Now i noticed tha remains constant. Do you believe that clock timing can make some difference if i change it?

Comment: Please provide more code. Preferably a minimal complete example. ISE webpack is deprecated. Vivado webpack provides better design interface imho (IP-integrator). You should also read the block descriptions: I remember both ISE and at least Vivado provide a link to the block data sheet/use guide for each block you instantiate.